# Big Data Speech analytics on Hadoop

Tags: analytics, bigdata, speech-to-text, sentiment-analysis

I am new to the analytics area and i am stumbled upon by a requirement to perform speech analytics on the call center audios. At this moment, its not very clear on what kind of analytics would be expected, but sentimental analytics is what i see. I have heard that there are commercial call center platforms available which has analytics built in. But I am looking for advices on using the Open source solutions to achieve the same. Needless to say, the amount of data is huge and big data platform is a must.

From my understanding,

1. Need to convert the huge set of audio files to text and load them into HDFS.

Question: What are the open source solutions available?

2 . Then perform sentimental analytics on the data loaded into HDFS with map\reduce.

Question: What are the open source solutions available to perform this?

I am sure i might have missed 1000 things wit my very basic understanding but any direction would greatly help.

Comment: For Hadoop speech processing, java-based Sphinx4 http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net is the best choice. Overall, this is not a type of question you might want on SO, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq for details.